# ValueError: could not convert string to float: Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

This is my code snippet where data2 is a dataframe.
Why isn't the string object converted to float?
Same code works for converting string to int64.

```
dt = np.dtype(object)  # Python object
df4 = data2['What was your +2 percentage?']
x=np.array(df4,dtype=dt)
y = x.astype(float)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you post what `data2` contains?

Comment: data1 = pd.read_csv('/home/ashutosh/Downloads/Data.csv') and data2 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

Comment: It's not easy to tell what the issue is without taking a look at the data.

Comment: the data is downloaded as  csv file from google forms. One of the data which must be floating type was changed to string object which gave rise to this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `df` is your data frame, you can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) to coerce your data into floats:

```
In [86]: pd.to_numeric(df['data'], errors='coerce')
Out[86]: 
0    1.0
1    2.0
2   -3.0
3    5.5
Name: data, dtype: float64

In [91]: pd.to_numeric(df['data'], errors='coerce').tolist()
Out[91]: [1.0, 2.0, -3.0, 5.5]
```

What you get is a list of floats, you can then convert it to a `np.array()`.